# How to encrypt a large file with limited disk quota?

Tags: unix, encryption, freebsd, quota

On a FreeBSD server, is there any way to encrypt a file, which is probably 90%+ of my quota?

I thought of using `split`, then after encrypting a file, delete the original.. but then, when I have all the split encrypted files, how could I merge them [using `cat files* > all` ], without using double disk quota? And how could I split the file without going over also? lol

I realize this might be impossible, if it is, then just say so.

Comment: Often your quota does not count against file in /tmp if this is the case you could put the encrypted output there

Comment: In place encryption does exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131810/in-place-encryption-with-gpg) is a post on SO that describes it pretty well, and its downsides. It is possible though.

[ccrypt](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ccrypt/) seems to be the way to go.